# Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password) during ambari hadoop installation

Tags: hadoop, ssh, ambari

I am trying to deploy a hadoop cluster using ambari, but when i select the hostnames with FQDN and proceed to configure I get the permission denied error for ssh.

STEPS:
1. generated rsa key using ssh-keygen as root.

2. changed permission for .ssh(700) and authorized_keys(640)
3. cat the public key to authorized_keys.
4. and copied the public key to all the hosts(authorized_keys) and changed the file permission as above.
5. I could ssh passwordless from ambari server host to all the other hosts.

But from ambari is failing to do the hadoop installation with below error.

```
SSH command execution finished
host=XXX, exitcode=255
Command end time 2015-06-23 10:44:07

ERROR: Bootstrap of host XXX fails because previous action finished with non-zero exit code (255)
ERROR MESSAGE: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).

STDOUT: 
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
```

Please dont mark this question as a duplicate. I could see other questions with same description but none of them mention about the Ambari ssh permission denied error.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I encountered the same problem with him.

`ssh -i <your_keypair> root@<your_host>`
I tried this but it wasn't solved.

Here's my solution

host1 ip:192.168.1.21

host2 ip:192.168.1.22

host3 ip:192.168.1.23

on host1:

```
rm -rf /root/.ssh
ssh-keygen -t dsa
cat /root/.ssh/id_dsa.pub >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
scp /root/.ssh/id_dsa.pub host2:/root/
scp /root/.ssh/id_dsa.pub host3:/root/
```

on host2:

```
rm -rf /root/.ssh
ssh-keygen -t dsa
cat /root/id_dsa.pub >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

on host3:

```
rm -rf /root/.ssh
ssh-keygen -t dsa
cat /root/id_dsa.pub >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

host1:/root/.ssh/id_dsa This's the file which you need.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to execute something like

`ssh -i <your_keypair> root@<your_host>`

from some other host. If this is not working, then you are using wrong keypair.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same message but it turned out the problem was user error. I had been uploading the *public key* to the Ambari installer, rather than the *private key*.

Answer (score 0):

Try using id_rsa file instead of copying and pasting its content in ambari web-app
Doing this fix the problem for me.