# HAWQ service check Fails From Ambari

Tags: hadoop, greenplum, ambari, hawq

We have small Hadoop-Hawq Cluster. In that, once of slave host service fails When I am executing the check of HAWQ services.

Getting following error From Ambari UI:

```
**stderr:** 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/PHD/3.0/services/HAWQ/package/scripts/service_check.py", line 9, in <module>
    HAWQServiceCheck().execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/libraries/script/script.py", line 123, in execute
    method(env)
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/PHD/3.0/services/HAWQ/package/scripts/service_check.py", line 6, in service_check
    hawq.verify_segments_state(env)
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/PHD/3.0/services/HAWQ/package/scripts/hawq.py", line 20, in verify_segments_state
    raise Exception("gpstate command returned non-zero result: {0}. Out: {1} Error: {2}".format(retcode, out, err))
Exception: gpstate command returned non-zero result: 255. Out:  Error: Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
 **stdout:**
(255, '', 'Permission denied, please try again.\r\nPermission denied, please try again.\r\nPermission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).\r\n')
```

Any help on it would be much appreciated ?

Comment: Hi @vickps, welcome to SO or sort of ... Have you tried to run the script in a verbose mode before asking the question here? It seems that there is a permission issue ... Look at that before going further. You know the expression 'step by step' ...

Comment: We are doing the  check from Ambari UI . and there is  no verbose option.

Comment: then you have a real issue ... What your sysadmin is saying...?

Comment: I am the sysadmin  and responsible person for HAWQ related issue

Comment: ... (gasp) @vickps

Comment: is there command to check the  service  with verbose option ?

Comment: Does it help @vickps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31010016/permission-denied-publickey-gssapi-keyex-gssapi-with-mic-password-during-ambar

Comment: or this one @vickps https://discuss.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/206099047-Host-registration-in-Ambari-fails-with-Permission-denied-

Comment: Thanks , Let me check  both the Link .

Comment: [root@Ambari ~]# ssh hawqmachine
Last login: Mon Jun  6 11:16:30 2016 from Ambari
[root@hawqmachine ~]#

Comment: When i am executing the command it is  picking from  ambari  all host and slave has ability to passwordless  SSH

Comment: when you connect through ssh via prompt is different when you run it in an automated way. Have a try with an automated script to see if things are the same in terms of connection

Comment: Sure .  Let me check run of the automated script using Ambari Command line.

Comment: any updates on what you have done?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113936/discussion-between-vickps-and-andy-k).

Answer (score 4):

HAWQ requires passwordless ssh access to all cluster nodes. Check if the system is configured to allow that, and execute the following hawq command to set up passwordless ssh on the nodes defined in your hostfile:

> `$ gpssh-exkeys -f hostfile (in version 1.x)`
>
> `$ hawq ssh-exkeys -f hostfile (in version 2.x)`