# Permission denied (publickey,password) on Apache-ambari when creating a cluster

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, cluster-computing, ambari

I'm installing **apache-ambari** on ubuntu 14.04. `IP:8080` on browser worked and I can connect to another host via `ssh`. I followed verified answer of this question [Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password) during ambari hadoop installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31010016/permission-denied-publickey-gssapi-keyex-gssapi-with-mic-password-during-ambar)
 and also [Host registration in Ambari fails with "Permission denied"](https://discuss.pivotal.io/hc/en-us/articles/206099047-Host-registration-in-Ambari-fails-with-Permission-denied-) But my problem has not yet been resolved.

**Error**:

```
Registration log for hadoopmaster
==========================
Creating target directory...
==========================

Command start time 2018-05-08 19:05:24

Permission denied (publickey,password).
SSH command execution finished
host=hadoopmaster, exitcode=255
Command end time 2018-05-08 19:05:24

ERROR: Bootstrap of host hadoopmaster fails because previous action finished with non-zero exit code (255)
ERROR MESSAGE: Permission denied (publickey,password).

STDOUT: 
Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

In this step, I want to create one cluster and add one node (myself as server or master). I set right permission for `ssh` and `authorized_keys`.
Is my private key wrong? Is my `FQDN`(hadoopmaster) wrong?
Note: I installed hadoop without apache-ambari on my system and it's OK.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

It should be a wrong private key or a wrong content of authorized_keys. Maybe you added/forgot to add some newline in any of these files when copy-pasting contents. You may try `ssh-copy-id` command to fill up authorized_keys file correctly

Comment: I did `ssh-keygen -t rsa`  and with `ssh-copy-id` copied `id_rsa.pub` in /home/user/other host. And for ambari, I enterd my `id_rsa` file.

Comment: did you try to connect to this host manually using generated ssh key? did you check `/var/log/auth.log` on other host to see if there are any related errors here? 
You may also try these tips https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-troubleshoot-ssh-authentication-issues-on-your-droplet

or run ssh command with increased verbosity (`ssh -vvv user@host`)